# one click upload (ocupload) jquery plugin and cakephp 2

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm trying to use the 'one click upload' plugin for jquery http://code.google.com/p/ocupload/wiki/Documentation

it's a plugin which changes the normal input type="file" into whatever element you want, for example a div, so when you click this div a file browser will open up allowing you to select a file to upload. It then submits a hidden form somewho involving an iframe, I believe the concept is well known but not to me.

Anyway, So far so good... I have my div which opens a file broswer.

The problem is that when a file is selected the plugin is supposed to auto-submit the form to an action which you define. This doesn't seem to be happening properly, and I think it's possibly to do with where I'm aiming the action of the form.

So in my view for adding a new 'tile' I have:

```
<div id="TileImageUpload">Upload an image</div>
```

Then to attach the javascript to the div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //one click image upload
    var myUpload = $('#TileImageUpload').upload({
            name: 'file',
            action: '../tiles/uploadImage',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            params: {upload:'Upload'},
            autoSubmit: true,
            onSubmit: function() {
                alert('submitted');
                $('#upload_status').html('').hide();
                loadingmessage('Please wait, uploading file...', 'show');
            },
            onComplete: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            onSelect: function() {}
    });



});
```

In the above the action parameter is meant to point to my my TilesController action=>uploadImage. which looks like:

```
function uploadImage() {
    if ($_POST["upload"]=="Upload") { 
        return 'wooHoo';
    } else {
        return 'BooHoo';
    }
}
```

**Note** I also tried echo'ing back 'WoHoo' ect but didn't make a difference.

So basically if there was a successful form post then it should return WooHoo to the javascript which should then alert it.

This ain't happening. Does anyone have an idea why. Like I said I think possibly to do with the form action but I've tried everyway I can think.

The actual JS for the plugin isn't big it might be over the top to post it all here. Its available at the link I posted above if some kind soul takes pity and fancies helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use 'return', but try 'echo'.

However, since you're not using a view-file for your action in this case you should also disable 'autoRender';

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

Otherwise CakePHP will throw a 'view not found' Exception.

Furthermore, to get the data posted inside CakePHP, use the [Request](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakerequest) object;

For example:

```
$this->autoRender = false;

if($this->request->is('post')) {
    echo 'data is posted. This is the content of the request:';
    debug($this->request->data);
} else {
    echo 'no form is posted';
}
```

Finally, if you want to return JSON data, see these parts of the manual

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakeresponse

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html